# How can I unnormalize MinMaxScaler?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use minimax scaler for my data... but I want to get the predicted data(output) unnormalized. I want to get the output with the original values not the normalized value..
Any one can help me...

My code for normalized data:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_X = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_Y = MinMaxScaler()
# fit_transform for training data:
X_train = scaler_X.fit_transform(train.values[:,1:])
y_train = scaler_Y.fit_transform(train.values[:,:1])
# only transform for test (unseen) data:
X_test = scaler_X.transform(test.values[:,1:])
y_test = scaler_Y.transform(test.values[:,:1])
```

Comment: Those transformers have `inverse_transform` method, use that: `preds = scaler_Y.inverse_transform(scaled_preds)`.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform - http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Plus, this is a `scikit-learn` question, and it has nothing to do with `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inverse_transform` with the corresponding min-max scaler object.

```
scaler_Y.inverse_transform(data)
```

Comment: Just to add some extra info in case OP or anyone wonders. When normalizing, you compute the mean and SD of the data. Then you perform the normalization. So intuitively, unnormalizing is just the reverse of this.

Answer (score 1):

**Do you reaaly need to normalize the target Y values as well?** The best is probably that you only normalize your X values and the model learns to predict the unnormalized correct label from the normalized inputs. So, you do not have to a conversion in the prediction time. Of course, the X_test has to be normalized as well.

Normalization helps because it solves problems like gradient exploding and scale differences between various features. Normalizing the target values is most of the time not neccessary